# R mongolite distinct error

Tags: r, mongodb, mongolite

I'm trying to get a list of distinct values from a mongodb database in R using `mongolite`, but I'm getting this error:

> Error: Unimplemented BSON type 17

```
db <- mongo("collection",url="mongodb://my:pass@mymongodb/db")
db.distinct("Price")
Error: Unimplemented BSON type 17
```

It looks like it is an error in either `mongolite::mongo_collection_distinct` or `jsonlite:::simplify` called by the `distinct` function. Unfortunately, I got a GUI crash when I tried to use `mongo_collection_distinct` on its own.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: That error comes from the `bson.c` module supplied by `mongodb` - https://github.com/jeroenooms/mongolite/blob/master/src/bson.c (line 80). It appears you have an unsupported type.

Comment: What value are you expecting to see, and how did you insert the data into mongo?

Comment: I'm connecting to an external mongo database. I'm expecting to see a vector containing the unique values.

Comment: I've checked the types in mongodb, they are definitely type 2. Interestingly, there is also an error in mongolite if you try to use $type in a find.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
db$aggregate('[{"$group":{"_id":"$Price"}}]',
               options = '{"allowDiskUse":true}')
```